# How do I set the block visibility with PHP?

Tags: 8, blocks

In a site running Drupal 8, I want to show my block in two cases: when my view page is shown and when a node of my content type is shown.

How do I set the block visibility with PHP?

Comment: is it a custom block??

Comment: No block Added by UI

Comment: Add condition by clicking on  configure block . You can restrict block by mentioning content type as well as page url

Comment: Both Not working together.

Comment: Clear cache and check error Reports also

Comment: Done but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core visibility configuration is not so good in combining multiple visibility condition.

The module [Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups) provides more tools to do this. You can decide whether all condition must pass (logical AND) or only one condition must pass (logical OR) and put the logic in a group and reuse it on different blocks.